# Entity Framework Core: How to dynamically get the DbSet from a derived Type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the following abstract class, named `Sector`:

```
public abstract class Sector
{
    public string ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public Sector(){}
 }
```

And a second class, `GICSSector`, wich inherits from `Sector`:

```
public class GICSSector: Sector
{
   public virtual ICollection<GICSIndustryGroup> IndustryGroups {get; set;}
}
```

I have the following `DbSet` in my `DbContext`:

```
public DbSet<GICSSector> GICSSectors {get; set;}
```

I am trying to write a generic method to loads data from a CSV file, create the objects on the fly and then store the objects in my SQLLite database:

```
public static void UpdateEntitiesFromCSV<T>(MyContextFactory factory, string fileName) where T : class
{
    var entities = new List<T>();

    // ... Load entities from the CSV
    // ... Create the objects and add them to the list

    // Add the objects to the database

    using (var db = factory.Create(new DbContextFactoryOptions()))
    {
         var set = db.Set<T>();

         foreach(T e in entities)
         {
             set.Add(e);
         }

         db.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

I use the fluent API to manage the tables:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //...

    // GICSSector    
    modelBuilder.Entity<GICSSector>().HasKey(s => new { s.ID }); 
    modelBuilder.Entity<GICSSector>().Property(s => s.ID).HasMaxLength(2);      
    modelBuilder.Entity<GICSSector>().Property(s => s.Name).IsRequired();     
    modelBuilder.Entity<GICSSector>().Property(s => s.Name).HasMaxLength(50);
}
```

If I run the code I get the following exception: ***SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: Sectors'***.

If I check the type with `typeof(T)` or using `myEntity.GetType()` I get the same expected result: `MyNamespace.GICSSector`

Why EF Core wants to store it in a table called "Sectors" (the base type) and not in the expected GICSSectors?

How can I fix it?

*Note*: The method is a generic one that won't be used to handle only classes that inherit from `Sector`.

Comment: Annotate the GICSSector class with the TableAttribute?

Comment: I use the fluent api, I updated the question

Comment: Then use fluent API to set table name? (see my answer)

Comment: anything worth seeing in DbContextFactoryOptions? ie you sure OnModelCreating is being called... probably! just checking. You using code first,... have you tried deleting the DB creates a new 1..., try remove the contractor from the base class..

Comment: Adding .ToTable("GICSSectors" ) worked only after a drop and a recreation of the DB but solved the problem.

Comment: so then i was right! ;-) good stuff

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tell EF explicitly what table to use:

```
[Table("GICSSectors")]
public class GICSSector: Sector
{
    public virtual ICollection<GICSIndustryGroup> IndustryGroups {get; set;}
}
```

or use fluent api:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<GICSSector>().ToTable("GICSSectors");
```